# How to control all the Navigation Bars from one file?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In my project(written programmatically) in some files I hide the Navigation Bar, in other files I change the Navigation Bar color. Yes, I can do this just writing code at every single file where I want some specific Navigation Bar, but its so buggy and not the right way.

I tried to write a class, subclass of UINavigationController, where I loop through all my viewControllers and hide the Navigation Bar in specific files, but its not working.

Can anyone please help me to figure out it? What is the right way to control all the Navigation Bars changes(actions) from one file?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is subclass the UINavigationViewController and override the pushViewController method. Your ViewControllers should conform to a protocol and you should check inside the pushViewController if the ViewController conforms to that protocol and if so check if it implemented the methods from the protocol and based on that layout your UI.

Example:

```
-(void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
 if ([controller conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)]) {
     id<MyProtocol> protocolVC = (id)controller;
     if([protocolVC barColor]){
         UIColor *color = [protocolVC barColor];
         //Set the bar color
     }
 }
 [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: Harry, thank you very much for your reply. I'm having problem to understand  some line of the code you provided. Could you please explain it? This is the code-  id<MyProtocol> protocolVC = (id)controller;
     if([protocolVC barColor]){
         UIColor *color = [protocolVC barColor];
         //Set the bar color
     }

Comment: So what this method is doing is checking if the `ViewController` conforms to that protocol `MyProtocol` in this case and the first `if statement` is that.  Now that we are inside the `if statement` we know the `ViewController` conforms to our protocol therefore we can cast it the protocol using `id<MyProtocol> protocolVC = (id)controller;` by doing so we can call all the `protocols methods` in this case the `barColor` method. Since protocols can have optional methods we also check that the `ViewController` has implemented this method just in case and if that succeeds we have the color. @Sergey

Comment: What I would do is make a `BaseViewController` `class` and make all the `ViewControllers` subclasses of `BaseViewController` then I would conform `BaseViewController` to `MyProtocol` and in there I would implement `barColor` with the default color of my choosing and then for the 4 `ViewControllers` that need the black color I would also implement the `barColor` method in those 4 `ViewControllers` which would return the black color. If you don't want to subclass it you could always make an extension to `ViewController` and conform it to `MyProtocol`.

Comment: Harry, it works great! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I wish to give a vote for your answer, but I don't have enough points. Definitely +1 to your karma though :)

Comment: Can you not mark it as the correct answer? @SergeyNevzorov

Comment: I'm grad I could be of help :)